# wireshark display payload data in strange way

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am using wireshark for mac to capture packet on my mac. I could view payload data in data view pane. I hope to export selected column into a csv file so I right click on the data area and apply it as column. Here I get a wired output display; the data column just shown as the check mark. How could I make things right?[image]
version stable 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tshark (Wireshark's CLI) to output the data component of packets like so:

```
$ tshark -T fields -e data
```

Data will be printed one item per line, so technically if you send this output to a file (`>`), this could be a valid CSV if there are no commas in the data.

You may want to look at tshark's [manpage](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).